# Android ListViewAdapter getView called multiple times

Tags: android, listview, getview

I have to set a Listview to full hight based on it's items because it's located inside a Scrollview. This works fine but I looked at the getView Methode in the Adapter and saw that it is called very often. Unfortunately I can't find the reason why...
Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    Log.e("called", position+"");
    back = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    filter = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    final RelativeLayout deleteContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteContainer);
    final ImageView deletAdd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    deletAdd.setScaleX(0.5f);
    deletAdd.setScaleY(0.5f);
    View backDelete = convertView.findViewById(R.id.View1);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    title.setTypeface(AppData.glogooregular);
    if (postList.get(position).getThumb() == null) {
        filter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        title.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) title.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        title.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
        title.getLayoutParams().height = AppData.height / 6;
    }
    Glide.with(context).load(postList.get(position).getThumb()).override(AppData.width, AppData.height / 6).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).into(back);
    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView comments = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    title.setText(postList.get(position).getTitle());
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    Calendar cal = DateToCalendar(new Date(Long.parseLong(postList.get(position).getTime()) * 1000));
    String month_name = month_date.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
    date.setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "." + month_name + " - " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " Uhr");
    if (postList.get(position).getCommentStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        comments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    comments.setText(postList.get(position).getComment_count());
    Drawable background = comments.getBackground();
    try {
        if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ((ShapeDrawable) background).getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                    + AppData.appInfo.getColorset().getJSONArray("colors").getJSONObject(0).getString("color")));
        } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            ((GradientDrawable) background).setColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                    + AppData.appInfo.getColorset().getJSONArray("colors").getJSONObject(0).getString("color")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Drawable backgroundDelete = backDelete.getBackground();
    try {
        if (backgroundDelete instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ((ShapeDrawable) backgroundDelete).getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                    + AppData.appInfo.getColorset().getJSONArray("colors").getJSONObject(0).getString("color")));
        } else if (backgroundDelete instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            ((GradientDrawable) backgroundDelete).setColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                    + AppData.appInfo.getColorset().getJSONArray("colors").getJSONObject(0).getString("color")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    comments.setTypeface(AppData.glogooboold);
    date.setTypeface(AppData.glogooboold); ...
```

The output when i start the Activity is:

```
02-04 05:29:06.117 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.117 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.117 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.118 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.118 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.118 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.118 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.119 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.119 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.119 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.119 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.120 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.120 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.120 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.120 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.120 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.121 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.121 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.121 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.122 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.122 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.122 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.122 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.123 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.123 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.123 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.123 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.124 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.124 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.124 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.124 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.124 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.125 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.125 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.125 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.125 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.126 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.126 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.126 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.126 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.127 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.127 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.127 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.127 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.128 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.128 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.128 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.128 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.128 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.129 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.129 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.129 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.129 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.129 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.130 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.130 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.130 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.130 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.130 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.131 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.131 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.131 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.131 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.132 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.132 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.132 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.132 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.132 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.133 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.133 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.133 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.133 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.133 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.134 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.134 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.134 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.135 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.135 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.135 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.136 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.136 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.136 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.136 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.136 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.137 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.137 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.137 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.137 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.137 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.138 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.138 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.138 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.138 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.139 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.139 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.139 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.139 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.139 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.140 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.140 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.140 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.140 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.141 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.141 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.141 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.141 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.141 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.142 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.142 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.142 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.142 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.142 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.143 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.143 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.143 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.143 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.144 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.144 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.144 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.144 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.144 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.145 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.145 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.145 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.145 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.145 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.145 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.146 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.146 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.146 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.147 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.147 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.147 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.148 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.148 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.148 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.148 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.149 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.149 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.149 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.149 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.149 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.150 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.150 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.150 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.150 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.150 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.151 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.151 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.151 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.151 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.152 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.152 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.152 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.152 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.152 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.153 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.153 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.153 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.153 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.223 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.224 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.224 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.224 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.225 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.225 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.230 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.231 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.231 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.231 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.231 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.232 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.232 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.232 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.232 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.233 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.233 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.233 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.233 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.234 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.234 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.234 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.234 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.235 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.235 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.235 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.236 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.236 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.236 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.236 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.236 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.237 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.237 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.237 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.237 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.237 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.238 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.239 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.240 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.240 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.240 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.241 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.241 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.241 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.241 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.242 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.242 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.242 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.242 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.242 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.243 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.244 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.244 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.244 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.244 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.245 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.245 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.245 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.245 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.245 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.246 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.246 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.246 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.246 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.246 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.247 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.247 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.247 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.247 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.248 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.248 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.248 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.248 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.248 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.249 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.249 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.249 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.249 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.249 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.250 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.250 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.250 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.250 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.250 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.251 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.251 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.251 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.252 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.252 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.252 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.252 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.252 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.253 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.253 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.253 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.253 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.253 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.254 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.254 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.254 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.254 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.255 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.255 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.255 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.255 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.256 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.256 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.256 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.257 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.257 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.257 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.257 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.258 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.258 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.258 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.258 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.258 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.259 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.259 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.259 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.259 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.260 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.260 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.260 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.260 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.261 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.261 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.261 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.261 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.261 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.262 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.262 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.262 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.262 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.263 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.263 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.263 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.263 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.264 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.264 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.264 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.264 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.265 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.265 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.265 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.265 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.266 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.266 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.266 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.266 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.267 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.267 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.267 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.267 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.268 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.268 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.268 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.268 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.269 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.269 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.342 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.343 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.343 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.343 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.344 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.344 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.344 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.345 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.345 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.345 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.346 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.346 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.346 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.347 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.347 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.347 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.348 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.348 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.348 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.349 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.349 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.349 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.349 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.350 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.350 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.351 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.351 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.351 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.352 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.352 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.352 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.352 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.352 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.353 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.353 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.353 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.353 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.354 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.354 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.354 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.354 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.354 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.355 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.355 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.355 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.355 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.356 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.356 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.356 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.356 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.356 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.358 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.359 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.360 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.361 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.361 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.361 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.362 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.362 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.362 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.362 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.363 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.363 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.363 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.364 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.364 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.364 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.365 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.365 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.365 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.365 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.365 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.366 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.366 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.366 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.366 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.367 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.367 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.367 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.367 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19
02-04 05:29:06.368 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 0
02-04 05:29:06.368 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 1
02-04 05:29:06.368 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 2
02-04 05:29:06.368 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 3
02-04 05:29:06.368 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 4
02-04 05:29:06.369 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 5
02-04 05:29:06.369 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 6
02-04 05:29:06.369 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 7
02-04 05:29:06.369 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 8
02-04 05:29:06.369 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 9
02-04 05:29:06.370 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 10
02-04 05:29:06.370 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 11
02-04 05:29:06.370 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 12
02-04 05:29:06.370 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 13
02-04 05:29:06.371 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 14
02-04 05:29:06.371 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 15
02-04 05:29:06.371 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 16
02-04 05:29:06.372 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 17
02-04 05:29:06.372 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 18
02-04 05:29:06.373 16968-16968/io.appful E/called: 19 ...
```

Comment: "I have to set a Listview to full hight based on it's items because it's located inside a Scrollview." - Doing this defeats the purpose of using a `ListView`. Use a vertically-oriented `LinearLayout` instead, with its `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: What's the problem actually if the getView is called often?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response the Problem is that I think that the Image is loaded often but I will try the idea with the linearlayout